# Make google +1 button hidden like parent div

Tags: javascript, css, google-plus-one

I have a modal box div, that has visibility: hidden; and after 5s it shows up thanks to a javascript function. Inside that div, I have code for google plus one button, but the thing is that before the modal box pops up, the button is already visible. I want it to appear at the same time as the modal box (5s after the page loads, not instantly). Is there any way to do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plusone size="tall" callback="g_click_function"></g:plusone>
<script>
    function g_click_function(){
        document.getElementById('greet_block_close').click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/z76vg/  I think you need to post more of your code or a demo site.

Comment: Thanks for setting that up Joseph. I changed it to visibility rather than display and it doesn't work. Could you just check please: [http://jsfiddle.net/z76vg/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/z76vg/1/)? I'll have to change it to display :)

Comment: that considered... I have no clue.  There is nothing that I can see that would cause this.

Answer (score 0):

First, add an id to the `<script>` tag, such as `mygone`:

```
<script id="mygone" type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
```

Then, if you're using jQuery (or onload for the body) hide it when the page loads:

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
   $('#mygone').next().hide();
});
```

Finally, when you're ready to show it, run this code:

```
$('#mygone').next().show();
```

I also created an example in JSFiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/EDTdY/2/.

Comment: that is most definitely not cross browser.  script elements aren't able to be hidden because they don't take up any space in the page.

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it in all browsers...+1 button doesn't work in IE<8 anyways, I hope it works in modern browsers... If not, I'll change it to display as Joseph showed me.

Comment: Did this dude just give a script an ID?  Wait, it gets better.  Did this dude just use DOM functions on a script tag?